# reset USB port, how to obtain same effect of physical disconnection or poweroff

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I have an headless system running Ubuntu 14, with a xtion pro live camera connected to do some live video elaboration.
Sometimes on boot (every morning is power on, but this is happening ramdomly) the camera is not recognized and dmesg shows:

usb 1-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

The camera is not even listed in lsusb.
What I tried without any success is:

- Computer reboot
- https://davidjb.com/blog/2012/06/restartreset-usb-in-ubuntu-12-04-without-rebooting/   (usb device it's not listed in lsusb)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/661/373541
- on BIOS fast boot is disabled
- can't rmmod/modprobe xhci_hcd as it's builtin
- https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl

The only working solution is to poweroff/poweron the computer (not feasible as is an headless system, it poweroff every night, and poweron every morning but I'd avoid waiting next day when the problem occurs).
Is there any solution to simulate the physical disconnection of the device (I not even sure if this would work) or the poweroff for what USB concerns?
Any ideas will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Here you might find your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux/12675749#12675749

Comment: it doens't work

Comment: Try `uhubctl -R -a cycle`. But it will work only if your hub supports per port power switching (to be recognized by uhubctl).

Comment: it's already in the attempts list without any success..

Comment: @rok: did you try with `-R`? Adding `-R` will try to use appropriate USB reset mechanism supported by your OS (Linux in this case).

Comment: You can refer to following link to unbind and bind usb bus!! https://zedt.eu/tech/linux/restarting-usb-subsystem-centos/

Comment: it doens't work, I came up with the idea that is an hardware issue specific to the sensor. Seems that only physically interrupting the power (that doens't happen in the reboot I guess) the problem is solved ..

Answer (score 2):

First, check whether the device port is USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 -

```
$ lspci | grep USB
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
```

Then, to elevate to root:

```
$ sudo -i
```

If the port is USB 3.0:

```
# ls  /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/
0000:00:14.0 bind  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
# echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
# echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
```

If the port is USB 2.0:

```
# ls  /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/
0000:00:14.0 bind  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
# echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
# echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
```

Comment: as I said.. I already tried this method without any luck..

Comment: yes @RomanRiabenko You are right, it was there in my output as well. it was a typo. fixed it now!!